# Vapor build failed when the amount of columns in Node are more than 18?

Tags: vapor

I'm using "Model" with function "makeNode" in Vapor, and I can successfully build and run the project when the table columns amount are less than about 14. 
But when my table columns goes to 19 or 20, then the Vapor starts to build very very slowly, and will report failed eventually. 
I have tried using MySQL or MongoDB, both got the same issue. So I'm wondering how to fix this issue when I need to use a table that consists of 20 columns. 
The below are the details:

```
final class TableName: Model {
    var id: Node?
    var column1: Int
    var column2: Int
    var column3: String
    var column4: String
    var column5: String
    var column6: String
    var column7: String
    var column8: String
    var column9: String
    var column10: String
    var column11: String
    var column12: String
    var column13: String
    var column14: String
    var column15: String
    var column16: String
    var createdAt: Double
    var updatedAt: Double

    init(column1: Int, column2: Int, column3: String, column4: String, column5: String, column6: String, column7: String, column8, column9: String, column10: String, column11: String, column12: String, column13: String, column14: String, column15: String, column16: String, createdAt: Double, updatedAt: Double) {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString.makeNode()
        self.column1 = column1
        self.column2 = column2
        self.column3 = column3
        self.column4 = column4
        self.column5 = column5
        self.column6 = column6
        self.column7 = column7
        self.column8 = column8
        self.column9 = column9
        self.column10 = column10
        self.column11 = column11
        self.column12 = column12
        self.column13 = column13
        self.column14 = column14
        self.column15 = column15
        self.column16 = column16
        self.createdAt = createdAt
        self.updatedAt = updatedAt
    }

    init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
        id = try node.extract("id")
        column1 = try node.extract("column1")
        column2 = try node.extract("column2")
        // from 2~16, etc... don't repeat here...
        updatedAt = try node.extract("updatedAt")
        createdAt = try node.extract("createdAt")
    }

    // Issue happened here... 
    // when the amount less than about 10, results are ok and build fast, 
    // but will build slowly and slowly when the number goes more and more, 
    // even build failed when table columns goes to about 18~20.
    func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
        var node = try Node(node: [
            "id": id,
            "column1": column1,
            "column2": column2,
            "column3": column3,
            "column4": column4,
            "column5": column5,
            "column6": column6,
            "column7": column7,
            "column8": column8,
            "column9": column9,
            "column10": column10,
            "column11": column11,
            "column12": column12,
            "column13": column13,
            "column14": column14,
            "column15": column15,
            "column16": column16,
            "createdAt": createdAt,
            "updatedAt": updatedAt
            ])
        return node
    }
}
```

And the build error message is:

> Command failed due to signal: Killed: 9

So, I would be appreciate for giving me any hint to fix this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the compiler. Type hinting (adding in `as Foo`, etc) is a good way to remedy a confused compiler.

Reporting the full output of the error to https://bugs.swift.org would help the team get it fixed ASAP.